# asp.net checkbox not checked on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know there are plenty questions asked about this, but I am not able to find an answer in my case.

The case: I have a dropdown and a placeholder on a page and, depending on the selected option, the related contents are loaded in. In content 3 I have a checkbox which doesn't post back the correct checked state.

The problem is that the dropdown does a postback and on top of this I am doing another postback on button click when the contents are loaded.

The example case:

Parent control:

```
public class MyAccount : BaseAuthControl
{
    protected PlaceHolder phContentMA;

    protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Page_Load(sender, e);  

        LoadStage(3);            
    }

    private void LoadStage(int index)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case 1:
                var oh = Page.LoadControl("OrderHistory");
                phContentMA.Controls.Add(oh);
                break;
            case 2:
                var st = Page.LoadControl("Statement");
                phContentMA.Controls.Add(st);
                break;
            case 3:
                var pa = Page.LoadControl("ProductAnalysis");
                phContentMA.Controls.Add(pa);
                break;
            case 4:
                var bo = Page.LoadControl("BackOrders");
                phContentMA.Controls.Add(bo);
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void cbMyAccount_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadStage(cbMyAccount.SelectedIndex);            
    }
}
```

Parent .ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="c#" Codebehind="MyAccount.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls.MyAccount"%>

Action: <asp:dropdownlist id="cbMyAccount" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbMyAccount_SelectedIndexChanged" />

<asp:PlaceHolder id="phContentMA" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

The problematic child control:

```
public class ProductAnalysis : BaseAuthControl
{
    protected Repeater rptrProducts;

    protected Literal ltStockCode;
    protected Literal ltStockDesc;
    protected Literal ltQtySold;
    protected Literal ltAmount;

    protected HyperLink lnkAddToCart;

    protected CheckBox chkMultiple;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        var saleStats = // results from the database;

        rptrProducts.DataSource = saleStats;
        rptrProducts.DataBind();
    }

    protected void rptrProducts_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem) return;

        var saleItem = e.Item.DataItem as TSaleStat;

        if (saleItem == null) return;

        var stockItem = GetItem(saleItem.StockCode);

        if (stockItem == null) return;

        if (CCUtils.AssignRepeaterControl(e, out ltStockCode, "ltStockCode"))
            ltStockCode.Text = stockItem.StockCode;

        if (CCUtils.AssignRepeaterControl(e, out ltStockDesc, "ltStockDesc"))
            ltStockDesc.Text = stockItem.ShortDesc;

        if (CCUtils.AssignRepeaterControl(e, out ltQtySold, "ltQtySold"))
            ltQtySold.Text = saleItem.QuantitySold.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if (CCUtils.AssignRepeaterControl(e, out ltAmount, "ltAmount"))
            ltAmount.Text = CCUtils.GetCurrencyPrice(Session, (decimal)saleItem.TotalPrice);

        if (CCUtils.AssignRepeaterControl(e, out lnkAddToCart, "lnkAddToCart"))            
            lnkAddToCart.NavigateUrl = stockItem.BuildBuyNowLink();

        if (CCUtils.AssignRepeaterControl(e, out lnkAddToCart, "lnkAddToCart"))
            lnkAddToCart.NavigateUrl = stockItem.BuildBuyNowLink();

        if (CCUtils.AssignRepeaterControl(e, out chkMultiple, "chkMultiple"))
        {                
            chkMultiple.Attributes.Add("value", stockItem.StockCode);
        }
    }

    protected void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        var stockCodes = new List<string>();

        if (!rptrProducts.IsAssigned()) return;

        foreach (RepeaterItem repeaterItems in rptrProducts.Items)
        {                
            foreach (var childControl in repeaterItems.Controls)
            {
                var checkBox = childControl as CheckBox;

                if (checkBox == null) continue;

                if (checkBox.Checked) // always false here
                    stockCodes.Add(checkBox.Attributes["value"]);
            }
        }

        var test = stockCodes;
    }
}
```

And the child .ascx code:

```
<%@ Control Language="c#"  Codebehind="ProductAnalysis.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls.ProductAnalysis" %>

<div id="viewProductsPurchased">   
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrProducts" OnItemDataBound="rptrProducts_ItemDataBound" EnableViewState="True">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Stock Code</th>
                        <th>Stock Description</th>
                        <th>Total Sold</th>
                        <th>Total Value</th>
                        <th colspan="2"><asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="uppercase" ID="Btn" OnClick="BtnClick" Text="Add selected to cart" UseSubmitBehavior="False" /></th> <!-- another postback with this button -->
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltStockCode" />
                        </td>                        
                        <td>
                            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltStockDesc" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltQtySold" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltAmount" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="buttonlink" ID="lnkAddToCart" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkMultiple" /> <!-- this checkbox never checked on postback -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

I have tried wrapping code into `!Page.IsPostBack`:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
var saleStats = // results from the database;

rptrProducts.DataSource = saleStats;
rptrProducts.DataBind();
}
```

In this case nothing is loaded because of the postback from dropdown.

I am open to any suggestions, fixes or workarounds to get this sorted - spent far too much time already.

P.S. sorry for the bloat of code and please ignore any missing closing tags if there will be any.

Comment: Use ajax and a web api to prevent post backs. That way you dont have to worry about storing the state

Comment: @LiverpoolOwen it is far too late to make such changes

Comment: Wrap `LoadStage(3);` inside `If (!IsPostback) { ... }`.

Comment: @Prabhat good spot, but unfortunately no change. Also tried to wrap the parent control into `UpdatePanel` with a hope it would handle postbacks differently, but no luck either

Comment: The values of the controls will not persist between postbacks if I set `EnableViewState="False"`. Remove this property and check again.

Comment: @Prabhat Removed it and now when I click the button the child control is not rendered. However, I unwrapped the `LoadStage(3)` from the `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` and bang! Thank you so much! Though not sure how the `EnableViewState="False"` on the `DropDownList` could cause such a headache. You can post an answer and I will be more that happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

([From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx)) View state is used automatically by the ASP.NET page framework to persist information that must be preserved between postbacks. This information includes any non-default values of controls.

View state is a repository in an ASP.NET page that can store values that have to be retained during postback. The page framework uses view state to persist control settings between postbacks. This keeps values between postbacks without storing them in session state

Here in your case setting this property to `false` the values of these controls got lost during a postback. Removing this property would help identifying if there is a change in dropdown selection or not.

Comment: Thanks again, @Prabhat